# Remove duplicate li elements from list on Ajax call

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am populating an `li` list with an ajax call. I have duplicate values in the table that I do not want in the `li`. Only unique values should be added to the `li` list. I know this should be addressed on the SQL side but for now I just need to be able to filter the list in jQuery.

HTML:

```html
<ul id="bookList">
</ul>
```

JS:

```js
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "getchapters.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(results) {


            $.each(results, function(index, result) {

                var Books = result.books.split(",");

                $("#bookList").append('<li>' + Books + '</li>');

            });
        }
    });
```

So if "Green eggs and Ham" book appears once, it is added to the list. The second time it appears it will be ignored.

Comment: Can you show some sample of the JSON you receive? Also, why are you splitting on the comma?

Comment: [{"category":"childrens","books":"Green eggs and ham","author":"drsuess"},{"category":"animations","books":"Green eggs and ham","author":"drsuess"}] I am splitting based on fields defined in my json object.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a separate array outside of the loop to track

```
var unique = [],
    books;
$.each(results, function(index, result) {
    books = result.books.split(",");
    if($.inArray(books, unique) === -1) {
        unique.push(books);
        $("#bookList").append('<li>' + books + '</li>');
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this. Doesn't work for me. Gives me a bunch of nested arrays without filtering the data. I think I will just have to do it on the sql side. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to remove duplicated from array before populating the list:

```
var Books = result.books.split(",");
var uniqueNames = [];

$.each(Books, function(i, el){
    if($.inArray(el, uniqueNames) === -1) uniqueNames.push(el);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

after this

```
var Books = result.books.split(",");
```

use this

```
Books = Books.reduce(function(c,l){
     if(c.indexOf(l) > -1){
        return c;
     }
     c.push(l);
     return c;
},[]);
```

now books has only unique items

** update : **
you can use sets

```
booksSet = new Set(Books);
```

now you have booksSet ,, you can use forEach on it or whatever you want ,,